# Building Microservices that shows server and rack awareness

Tags: cloud, microservices

I would like to build a microservices that can provide me the data about the Rack and server awareness. Like which server is present in which rack, this would help in the deployment service that I am building, where I need to make sure the deployment happens on multiple servers that are distributed in different racks and not deployed to same rack.

Are there any open source or documentation that I can go through which provides information on building a resilient service for servers and racks.

I am trying to find some good documentation but I don't seem to find any helpful ones

Comment: it looks like this has nothing todo with microservices or cloud. Could you please remove the microservices and cloud tags from your question?

Comment: Use Raft protocol for leader election. Cloud native services generally don't use rack awareness, since pods are always ephemeral. Kubernetes StatefulSet are an exception